# Enabling access to data and displaying that data on two different types of Views

Tags: swift

I am accessing a Realm database to load values in my iOS app.  The first one works fine.  I have a UIViewController with UITextFields.  The big picture is that i:

1. Define the outlets in the ViewController and connect them to the mainstoryboard UITextFields. There are three fields
2. I set up an array and load the results of the Realm query from a PersonData.swift data model. Three properties defined in the swift file.
3. In viewDidLoad I call the function to loadPersonData.
4. The first thing in the loadPersonData func is to put the realm.objects including three properties into the three fields that are defined by the Outlets at the top of the ViewController.
5. They load perfectly, are editable, and I can save the values of the data entry from the screen to the Realm database with a Realm modify. I can show you this code if you want to see it.

This is all working fine.  Now my problem. My next View is a UITableViewController, with prototype cell, and three UILabels in each single cell row.  This code has in the past used an Array for testing and that worked fine to load sample data back to the rows.  I want to now read Realm data and scroll up and down with the three fields in each row.  Later, when I select one,I will expose in another View all of the properties of that object called Year which is approximately 10 properties or UITextFields that can be edited.

1. I was told to build a subclass for the protype cell that will be a sub to the UITableViewCell.

   class BYMyCell: UITableViewCell {
2. I put the Outlets for the three UILabels from the prototype cell into the BYMyCell.swift subclass. These outlets are connected to the UILabels defined in the prototype cell.
3. I saw one suggestion about putting the same outlets in the first businessYearViewController where all the row support functions were located.  I was told to add the = nil to these outlets.

   @IBOutlet weak var yearLabel: UILabel! = nil
   @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel! = nil
   @IBOutlet weak var startingDateLabel: UILabel! = nil
4. Now when I try to move the Results of the Realm query from the three properties to the three Labels there appears to be nil in all the fields.  I can see the data come into my businessYearViewController where I make the query, but I am having trouble putting the data into the Outlets in the BYMyCell.swift data model for exposure on the view/screen.

If I should post my two files, I will try to put them in a response.  Thanks for your help. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with my lack of knowledge of processing TableViewController and prototype cell coordination.  My rows are simple.  One row, three labels. I will also have an add button at the top right corner and the ability to edit the fields in another View for data entry and changes.

Edited one hour later with information.  This is my loadBusinessYear func.

```
func loadBusinessYearData() {
    businessYearArray = realm.objects(YrData.self)
    print(businessYearArray!.count)
    print(businessYearArray?[0])
    
    if businessYearArray!.count > 0 {
            yearLabel.text = businessYearArray?[0].year
            descriptionLabel.text = businessYearArray?[0].yearType
            startingDateLabel.text = businessYearArray?[0].startingDate
            
      } else {
            yearLabel.text = "Sample Name"
            descriptionLabel.text = "Sample .com"
            startingDateLabel.text = "Sample Date"
      }
 }
```

The two print statements at the top give you the 1 for the count and the object properties as Optionals.

```
1
Optional(YrData {
    ydID = 0;
    year = 2020;
    yearType = Business Open;
    startingDate = 12/28/2019;
    firstWeekEndDate = 01/03/2020;
    lastWeekEndDate = 01/03/2021;
    firstQtrTotal = 520;
    secondQtrTotal = 520;
    thirdQtrTotal = 520;
    fourthQtrTotal = 520;
    leapYearExtraWeek = 40;
    yearContains53Weeks = 1;
    laborReporting = List<LaborReportData> <0x600000a15290> (

     );
    expenseAccounting = List<ExpenseAccountData> <0x600000a15440> (

    );
})
```

The data subclass is BYMyCell swift file.
import UIKit

```
class BYMyCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var yearLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var startingDateLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: I'm having a bit understanding your terms, but isn't the problem merely that you've given the job of talking to the database and storing the resulting data to a _view controller_? It's no business of the view controller to do any of that. You need a separate networking service object and a separate data store / access object, because the data represents the state of your _app_, not of any one view controller. That way, all view controllers can fetch or subscribe to the information, and any change in the data is promulgated automatically to everyone who is following it.

Comment: Also on a more granular level it should not be anyone's business to stuff interface into the cell's labels except the cell itself. Just hand the cell the data it is to display and let the cell worry about what that means in terms of visible interface.

Comment: So, are you saying to pass the three fields that I have received from the DB to the cell class and let the cell's class post it to the appropriate outlet?